# How do I change my update server in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, updates, 18.04

The first thing I did after installing 16.04 LTS was to change my update server to Main Server. I can not find a similar option in Ubuntu 18.04.

How do I change it?

Comment: Show Applications --> Software & Updates --> Ubuntu Software --> Download From.... Cannot see this?

Comment: got it. thanks. Ubuntu 16.04 used to have it in settings so I was used to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the terminal and type `software-properties-gtk` 
. From the opened window, open the drop down menu in front of **Download from:** and select **main server**

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but one needs to install using `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk` in case one is using KDE in place of GNOME

Answer (score 3):

You can open the Software & Updates app in Ubuntu and change and change **Download from** to the **Main Server** as mentioned @Eskander:

[image: Software & Updates]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on KDE you don't need `software-properties-gtk` instead you can use `Muon Package Manager` which you can find from Application launcher.

Then just go to `Muon Package Manager`->settings->configure software sources and then select your desired server(In this case main server).