# unable to install libxml2-utils on ubuntu 20.04 wsl

Tags: apt, 20.04

```
me@mecomp:~$ sudo apt install libxml2-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxml2-utils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 22 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 189 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml2-utils amd64 2.9.10+dfsg-5 [36.9 kB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libxml2-utils amd64 2.9.10+dfsg-5
  File has unexpected size (483 != 36940). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:85608055aeecbed9f59eccf49ebad936c5fb6dc3297b244ab5911ddbf1d923c8
   - SHA1:7a098c90d8534824acb8c1d2090d4b5e6e9cf3d7 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:eef0cdd73b3f97c8c604f8dcf490777c [weak]
   - Filesize:36940 [weak]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2-utils_2.9.10+dfsg-5_amd64.deb  File has unexpected size (483 != 36940). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:85608055aeecbed9f59eccf49ebad936c5fb6dc3297b244ab5911ddbf1d923c8
    - SHA1:7a098c90d8534824acb8c1d2090d4b5e6e9cf3d7 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:eef0cdd73b3f97c8c604f8dcf490777c [weak]
    - Filesize:36940 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

then tried
me@me comp:~$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils

Comment: updated windows to version 1903

Comment: updates to wsl2

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes "Failed to fetch ... File has unexpected size. Mirror sync progress?" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182803/what-causes-failed-to-fetch-file-has-unexpected-size-mirror-sync-progress)