# Problem with apt-get update on Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 20.04, update-manager

**When I type in the sudo apt-get update I get this output**

```
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Get:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98,3 kB]
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [318 kB]
Get:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [190 kB]
Get:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [119 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Ign:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:34 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:35 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [196 kB]
Err:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (195784 != 195720). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:195720 [weak]
   - SHA256:620989b440f546d66d39a063c6e8c049e6f716f0da9f510ebf1da727be3f5844
   - SHA1:96786274267a2bfce9c0b3c6bbc7b8e4076d08d8 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:6b22100a971f517dd23973ba9a242c8c [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 18:58:05 +0000
Get:34 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [177 kB]
Err:34 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Get:35 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.468 B]
Err:35 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  
Get:36 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]
Get:37 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]
Get:38 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3.096 B]
Get:39 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages [2.268 B]
Get:40 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Translation-en [1.448 B]
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Ign:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.972 B]
Err:41 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File has unexpected size (1976 != 1972). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1972 [weak]
   - SHA256:3d9adb8ec018eafe9e452377669976073b7e893d89a0664392c1435c2d256b7e
   - SHA1:347c09e2129d07363b358e6459655fa191ce9de8 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:a16154af0d5dc497f1d7d365cbd29897 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 18:58:28 +0000
Fetched 212 kB in 2s (124 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (195784 != 195720). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:195720 [weak]
    - SHA256:620989b440f546d66d39a063c6e8c049e6f716f0da9f510ebf1da727be3f5844
    - SHA1:96786274267a2bfce9c0b3c6bbc7b8e4076d08d8 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6b22100a971f517dd23973ba9a242c8c [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 18:58:05 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (1976 != 1972). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1972 [weak]
    - SHA256:3d9adb8ec018eafe9e452377669976073b7e893d89a0664392c1435c2d256b7e
    - SHA1:347c09e2129d07363b358e6459655fa191ce9de8 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:a16154af0d5dc497f1d7d365cbd29897 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 07 Aug 2020 18:58:28 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried doing `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` but the problem still persists.

Comment: Perhaps a reboot and try again? It appears to me that the first file in question that fails [Components-amd64.yml.xz](http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz) here is 1976 bytes. Direct link here [in this directory](http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/) . It is odd that what is being download is of a different size than the [files on the server](http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/)

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: can you try "apt-get clean" and try one more time? if that doesn't work perhaps try editing /etc/apt/sources.list and adjust repos like to look like so: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu instead of http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Comment: It worked! Thank you guys for the help and for being comprehensive!

Comment: nice! which of the two solutions worked for you?

Comment: The "apt-get clean", I guess is a simple line but I didn't see this command in any place, and I'm still a very noob Linux user.

Comment: From my understanding of this error, the `apt clean` didn't fix this, but was merely a matter of chance. The error shows up when the mirrors aren't in sync. Not all mirrors sync at the same time. I *strongly* suspect that somewhere between the time of questioning and the time they ran the update anew, the mirrors finished syncing. The running of `sudo apt clean` is just merely coincidental.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

apt-get clean worked! Thanks for the help from all of you.

Comment: why did you have to write  your own answer and accept it. instead of accepting the one that actually helped you ?

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I had to change the Ubuntu Software Update server from Brazil to the USA, then run:

```
$ apt-get clean
$ apt-get update
```

And that worked.

Answer (score 10):

The reason this happens is because not all the mirrors get updated at the same time. For a variety of reasons, updates get rolled out on a schedule and can take a few days for all the mirrors to be in sync.

If you see this problem, the best solution is to just take a nap or wait until the following day. If you'd like confirmation, or to see when your mirrors are updated, you can actually just [look here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). That will show you the status of mirrors, including how far behind they may be in the sync process.

You can also change your mirrors to new ones, which might be a good idea if it's a major security issue that you're updating to fix.

If you decide to change your mirrors, open 'Software & Updates' from your 'Preferences' and the very first tab has a drop down menu labeled 'Download From:' and pick alternative mirrors. If you're curious, it's generally considered best practice to pick the mirrors that are geologically closest to you.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today! (Ubuntu 21.10)
I changed from "Brazil" to "Main Server"
Then typed:

```
sudo apt clean  
sudo apt update
```

And now things are working as intended

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get clean` didn't worked for me.
Found the solution here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1229971

"Open Software & Updates and change **Download from** to **Main Server**"

Answer (score 1):

On the top right of the screen a red ! was displayed. When I clicked it a message said there is either a network problem or a problem with the sources and I should click **Show updates** to update the sources manually or check them. When I clicked **Show updates** the update manager said the software on my pc is actual. First I thought this is just a temporary problem but a few days later there was the same problem.

KGIII's answer helped me. Thanks! He posted, changing the mirrors could solve the problem. For me it works, with the difference that he posted "it's generally considered best practice to pick the mirrors that are geologically closest to you" and I chose **Main server**.

Then updates have been downloaded!

Today the same error happened again so I set **Server for *My Country*** again!
===========================================================

After that, update download works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following code:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add text: deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
or
deb http://usa.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
to modify /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1363092/