# Ubuntu 20.04 trouble with "Software & Updates" - "Error while refreshing cache"

Tags: apt, updates, proxy

In the "Software & Updates" application, when I check/uncheck any sources or ppa and click "close", I get this (which is normal):

[image: Screenshot 1]

After clicking "Reload", I have these errors:

[image: Screenshot 2]

It seems like the problems with proxy. I do use proxy, but even when I disable it in "Settings", the problem remains. However, I don't have any problem with `sudo apt update`.

I don't have any proxy-related `env` variables, nor proxies for `apt`. I don't know why it keeps reporting proxy issues.

**Edit 1**: The output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                           
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and paste its full output to question body. If long - use pastebin and share a link.

Comment: @trondhansen Synaptic is just a front-end and no, you shouldn't run a "partial update". We need to see the full error messages as requested by N0rbert.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182803/what-causes-failed-to-fetch-file-has-unexpected-size-mirror-sync-progress/1229971#1229971

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo ldconfig /usr/bin/gpg`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677711/114401

It worked for me. `sudo apt update` now works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up dis-selecting the repos (that were showing an error in the apt-get update message) from the in the "other sofware" section of updater's settings.

I also selected the "best server" in the "download more" menu of the "ubuntu software" section of "software updater's settings".

P.S. I also updated from LTS to non-LTS but I doubt that had anything to do with it.

after this I no longer get the annoying error message (Which is frankly very hard to close if the cancel button is hidden).