# Mendeley Update File Unexpected Size

Tags: mendeley

I am using Mendeley Desktop.

When i click Mendeley, update notification popped up. Then i tried to update it but i am getting unexpected file size error as shown in below. Any idea to overcome this ?

Thanks

```
Get:10 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease [2.456 B]
Hit:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                
Get:12 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages [632 B]
Err:12 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
  File has unexpected size (634 != 632). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 162.159.133.86 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:632 [weak]
   - SHA512:434dca5f31e158b617641e9b4608e4f8d03c53937cb5c466bcbd62d319b59dfe41d0e0fe25923d9f9e903df0f58c1aa57a321335c23c013f9a65599f83a12700
   - SHA256:4efebe383187fb3f9593c68732ccb470d14a73d5d47c91c4e904220e5ec3fbd7
   - SHA1:bcfce2e7936b9d88e6399722a105c2cada390288 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3a1d84efbff2f1303db4c3222cd2f6e1 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 13:13:36 +0000
Get:13 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages [633 B]
Hit:14 https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done                        
E: Failed to fetch https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (634 != 632). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 162.159.133.86 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:632 [weak]
    - SHA512:434dca5f31e158b617641e9b4608e4f8d03c53937cb5c466bcbd62d319b59dfe41d0e0fe25923d9f9e903df0f58c1aa57a321335c23c013f9a65599f83a12700
    - SHA256:4efebe383187fb3f9593c68732ccb470d14a73d5d47c91c4e904220e5ec3fbd7
    - SHA1:bcfce2e7936b9d88e6399722a105c2cada390288 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:3a1d84efbff2f1303db4c3222cd2f6e1 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 13:13:36 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by changing the update server in ubuntu 20.04.

[How do I change my update server in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029440/how-do-i-change-my-update-server-in-ubuntu-18-04)
Following the solutions in the link above.

Type in the terminal: software-properties-gtk

From the opened window, open the drop down menu in front of Download from: and select main server.

Then do sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade and it should work.
This worked for me!

Comment: thank you man it worked!